# Matplotlib doesn't show proper font on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I installed matplotlib with all dependencies on ubuntu 14.04 from source

```
Processing dependencies for matplotlib==1.3.1
Searching for nose==1.3.3
Best match: nose 1.3.3
Processing nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
Removing nose 1.3.1 from easy-install.pth file
nose 1.3.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing nosetests script to /usr/local/bin
Installing nosetests-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
Searching for pyparsing==2.0.1
Best match: pyparsing 2.0.1
Adding pyparsing 2.0.1 to easy-install.pth file
Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for tornado==3.1.1
Best match: tornado 3.1.1
tornado 3.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for python-dateutil==1.5
Best match: python-dateutil 1.5
python-dateutil 1.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Searching for numpy==1.8.1
Best match: numpy 1.8.1
numpy 1.8.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

When i try to plot something matplotlib doesn't show x ticks right as you can see from here
http://bayanbox.ir/id/4106587232464013527?view

Source:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.random(50)})
df.index=pd.date_range('2000-01-02', periods=50)
plt.plot_date(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.Val, fmt='-')
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%y%b\n%d'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: I think peresian is default language

Comment: Thank you so much changing default language helped and problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib uses [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for working with date formatting in ticks. `strftime` will use your computer's locale to choose the correct version of certain date formats, for instance "January" vs "Januar" for English vs German.

Your issue arises because your default language is Persian. Matplotlib is trying to plot using  Persian but is failing at encoding it properly (resulting in the squares).

Your choices to fix this are to either change the default language of your computer, or to set the `locale` of your Python code using the [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) builtin module.